# How to fix " There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2' erro in django view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I use "insync" api on the Django rest framework, but I get this error at runtime:

> "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'"

When I use from this code in the python file directly, there is no problem, but when I'm using in Django framework, I get this error.

How do I solve this problem?

- Python 3.7
- Django 2.2
- djangorestframework 3.9.2
- ib-insync 0.9.46
- ibapi 9.73.7

#### Attempt

```
from ib_insync import *
....

def Sendorder(request, format=None):         
.....

     ib = IB()        
     ib.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=7498, clientId=100, timeout=10)
     contract = ib.Stock(symbol, 'SMART', 'USD')
     ib.qualifyContracts(contract)

.....
```

#### Error

> File "C:\newsystem\env\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\util.py", line
>   228, in
>       loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Li
>   ncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
>       % threading.current_thread().name) RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.